# Capacitors and resistors shown as OPEN and SHORT in Schematics design

Tags: power, wireless, schematics, transmitter

I am designing a wireless power Transmitter circuit and mostly following this datasheet for Wireless transmitter IC :-
http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/power/switching_regulator_system/bd57020mwv-e.pdf

In the BOM table on Page 28-29, there are several capacitors and resistors which are shown in the Application Example Circuit but in BOM, there are marked as "OPEN" So i was wondering that if this "OPEN" means same as DO NOT MOUNT.
Also the resistor and a common mode choke are marked as "SHORT". Are they shorted? Example:-

Capacitor CCLMP and Resistor RCLMP "open" [CAP CCLMP and RES RCLMP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9bOJ.png)

Similarly, ROSC as short and COSC1 COSC2 as open [ROSC and COSC1 COSC2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VapC1.png)

Answer (score 0):

The fact the data sheet offers no values next to these components should give you a clue that OPEN does indeed mean not fitted, otherwise what would you fit.

For me personally it would then follow that the SHORT does mean short too.